# Create Shopping Cart and Insert data to Database using JSP

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jsp, shopping-cart

I have a Shopping Cart project using Session and insert data to database. 
My showCart.jsp :

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Shopping Cart Details</h1>
<table width=50%>
<tr><td>Item ID</td><td>Number of item in Shopping Cart</td></tr>
<%
    java.util.Enumeration em = session.getAttributeNames(); 
    for(;em.hasMoreElements();){
       String id= em.nextElement().toString();
    //get value from session object (see HttpSession)
       String count=session.getAttribute(id).toString();
       out.println("<tr>");
       out.println("<td>"+id+"</td>");
       out.println("<td>"+count+"</td>");
       out.println("</tr>");
    }
%>
</table>
<h2><a href="itemList.jsp">Items List</h2>
<br>
<h2><a href="checkout.jsp">Check-out</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

In my showCart.jsp, it's responsible to get Product that user requested (addtoCart) and show it. 
In my Checkout.jsp

```
<%@page import="DAO.DAO_Product"%>
<%@page import="Entity.Product"%>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Checkout!</h1>
<%
    DAO_Product dao = new DAO_Product();
    int count = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("count"));
    int id = Integer.parseInt("id");
    Product pro = new Product(id,count);
    int n = dao.addBill(pro);
    if(n>0){
        out.println("Your request has been approved");
    }
    session.invalidate();
 %>

 <h2><a href="itemList.jsp">New Shopping Cart</h2>


 </body>
 </html>
```

In checkout.jsp, It will invalidate session and insert data into Database (which customers requested). My problem is: I cannot insert "count" parameter, and it throws Exception :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServlet    Wrapper.java:548)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.jav    a:471)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
org.apache.jsp.checkout_jsp._jspService(checkout_jsp.java:73)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.jav    a:433)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Any idea to fix my problem ? Thank you.

Comment: your count may be null so

Comment: Indeed, insert a null check . Also what is the meaning of this: "    int id = Integer.parseInt("id");" You are parsing string to integer.

Comment: @SpringLearner : yeah, i understand, but i dont know how to " get " it to database ( with each of id )

Comment: @Tomek : to insert it into database, my ID in db has Int data type.

Comment: You can parse using parseInt() strings like "12", "-2341", "123", but not "blabla" , "blabla" isn't a number and you have parseInt("id"), "id" isn't a number. Your database isn't any concern. You probably wanted to do something like int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

Comment: @Tomek : hmm, seems it is not main prob, can u give me some ideas abt my " count " ?

Comment: You have parse issues as @Tomek said. Also you are trying to get item information from request parameters but the info is stored in session. You use simple links to navigate and you aren't passing any request parameters that's why you get null value for count and then the parser thow the exception